# How to set the value of “hostNameAliases” in Gatling

Tags: scala, testing, fiddler, gatling, scala-gatling

I’ve been using Gatling for 4-5 months and I’m a bit stuck with what seems to be a simple problem. I’m new to scala.

*hostNameAliases is not applied*

I’m debugging the script through a fiddler.
In the fiddler, I brought out a new column with the IP.
But in this column, I do not observe that the value from the “hostNameAliases” parameter is substituted in the IP
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8WsU.png)

Code in Gatling

```
  val httpProtocolWeb: HttpProtocolBuilder = http
    .hostNameAliases(Map("test.com" -> List("333.333.33.33")))
    .baseUrl("https://test.com")
    .acceptHeader("*/*")
    .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate, br")
    .acceptLanguageHeader("ru,en;q=0.9")
    .header("referer", "https://test.com")
    .check(status.in(200,204))
```

I use a valid IP. I specified 333… as an example

I see the real IP test.com in fiddler (test.com - as an example)

But since I set the “hostNameAliases” parameter, I should see its value, but unfortunately I don’t see it
In netstat I don't see the IP either

Comment: Already answered on Gatling's community forum where the question was double posted: https://community.gatling.io/t/how-to-set-the-value-of-hostnamealiases/8290/4